# Maven repository archive including build/plugin dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

My Client wants to be able to build  our project from source but does not want to connect to the internet to get any dependencies for the build. Note this will include plugin dependencies.

My proposal is that we provide the client with an archive containing all the dependencies in the correct Maven repo file structure, including checksums and meta information. They can then use this as an internal maven repo.

I have configured the maven-assembly-plugin to create such an archive, however it doesn't include all the build/plugin dependencies that their Maven will require to perform the build.

Does anyone know of a way to include build time dependencies in the archive, or can suggest another way to grab these dependencies and wrap them up in the correct structure.

Many thanks,
Pat

Comment: Strange... no connection to the internet ?...

Comment: IS there an option to set-up local Maven repository (Nexus, Artifactory) and install all the required artifacts?

Comment: @khmarbaise - there's no connection to the internet from their build environment.

Comment: @Nishant - Well, they want us to provide them with the internal repository. They can serve that repo however they want. I've suggested a simple file URL as they only want to prove the build, not do any active development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a clean repository, you can run `mvn dependency:go-offline`.  This will download all the `plugins` and `dependencies` relevant to the project.   You can verify that this is good by doing an *offline* build (`mvn -o clean install`).

Once this works fine, you can create an archive of the repository and the sources and pass it on.

Comment: That's great. In combination with khmarbaise's suggestion to use a clean repo in hudson, I think I can get something working.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to spend time on validating this, as we're convincing the client to allow internet access. I think this answer fits the bill though. Especially in conjunction with khmarbaise's tip about private repos in Hudson/Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look into the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and furthermore i would suggest to do a complete compile and package and after that you can package the local repository from that user ($HOME/.m2/repository). Than you have everything which is needed to do a full compile etc.

Comment: I considered packaging the local repo, but I'd like to run this on our build server, which builds many more projects than this one. I will take a look at the dependency plugin though. Thanks.

Comment: In the build server you can configure to use a clean repository during the build (Hudson/Jenkins supports such a thing).

Answer (score 0):

Try `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`.  This will copy all the dependencies to a directory `target\dependency`.

However, I'm not certain whether this includes the dependencies necessary to build, as well and those necessary to install the compiled output.